# Java is changing my leading spaces to question marks

Tags: java, minecraft

I am using this inside of a minecraft mod to read and write file and all the leading space are being converted to ? in the file.

**file input sample:**

```
{
   "ReturnToStart": "1b",
```

**file out put sample:**

```
{
???"ReturnToStart": "1b",
```

```
//xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
var ips = new java.io.FileInputStream("ABC.json");
var fileReader = new java.io.InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8");
var data1 = fileReader.read();
var data;
var start1 = "";
while(data1 != -1) {    
data =  String.fromCharCode(data1);   
start1 = start1+data;
data1 = fileReader.read();
}
fileReader.close();
var  fileWriter = new java.io.FileWriter("J_out2.txt");
fileWriter.write(start1);
fileWriter.close();
```

Comment: You're combining java and JavaScript. They are 2 complete diffrent languages. There will be errors then you put them together

Comment: There are no errors -it can read and write fine, just these strange characters at the beginning of each line - I think it has something to do with the carriage returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Nashorn in Java 8. Basically that is JavaScript running in a Java VM with access to all Java objects. I don't think those are normal spaces, and I suspect these are non breaking spaces (with code 160). It would be interesting to see what the value of `data1` is at these positions.

The JavaScript method `String.fromCharCode` doesn't convert UTF-8 codes properly in Nashorn. Actually this will never work because in UTF-8 a single character can be split over multiple characters, and the value that comes back from `read` is limited to 16 bits. Not enough.

Below is probably what you need. I have included but commented the `start1` variable because you may want to use that in your code, but is not needed.

```
var fileReader = new java.io.InputStreamReader(
    new java.io.FileInputStream("ABC.json"), "UTF-8");
var bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(fileReader);
var fileWriter = new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(
    new java.io.FileOutputStream("J_out2.txt"),"UTF-8");
var line;
// var start1=new java.lang.StringBuilder();
while(line=bufferedReader.readLine()) {
  // start1.append(line);
  // start1.append('\n');

  fileWriter.write(line);
  fileWriter.write('\n');
}
fileWriter.close();
bufferedReader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ips = new java.io.FileReader("ABC.json");
var data1 = ips.read();
var data;
var start1 = "";
while(data1 != -1) {    
data =  String.fromCharCode(data1);   

if (data1 ==11 ||data1 ==12 || data1 ==10) {
data1 = ips.read();
continue;
}
//npc.say(data1+"  "+ data);
data =  String.fromCharCode(data1); 
start1 = start1+data;
data1 = ips.read();
}
ips.close();
npc.say(start1);
```

Well I took out line feed, vertical tab, and form feed (10,11,12) and it works.